# How can i indicate the strings

Tags: python, string

```
 long =   """ADDRESS: Some place in the world
    TEL: 555 5555 5555 TYPE: Apartment/High
    Data Accuracy: Very heigh building with plenty of corroborating data"""
```

Lets assume i have a long string like that, i would like to parse them up and add to my dict

```
mydict = {'Adress':[],'Tel':[],'Type':[],'Data Accuracy':[]}
```

I have tried this

```
import re
x = re.split('ADRESS',long)
```

However this doesnt enough i would like parse them into 4 pieces and add them into mydict.`x = re.split('ADRESS',long)` this only parses it to one peace.

Comment: Use a regular expression to match the indicators.

Comment: How can i use it is there any method that you know?

Comment: Read the tutorial at www.regular-expression.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll still have a little bit of clean up to do i.e. remove front and trailing white space so `strip()` but this will work as asked:

```
import re

long = """ADDRESS: Some place in the world
    TEL: 555 5555 5555 TYPE: Apartment/High
    Data Accuracy: Very heigh building with plenty of corroborating data"""

x = re.split(r"[a-zA-Z]+:",long)
print(x)
# ['', ' Some place in the world\n    ', ' 555 5555 5555 ', ' Apartment/High\n    Data ', ' Very heigh building with plenty of corroborating data']

clean = []
for item in x:
    if item != "":
        clean.append(item.split('\n')[0].strip())
print(clean)
# ['Some place in the world', '555 5555 5555', 'Apartment/High', 'Very heigh building with plenty of corroborating data']
```

Comment: I have a question, why it is not working as when we dont pass in a to z brackets. [a-zA-Z] this works fine but ' [ADDRESS TEL TYPE Data Accuracy]+: ' when i pass in like this it is not working as the a to z brackets [a-zA-Z]

Comment: It’s because it’s a regex not a list like in Python so in this context it’s only matching the characters a through z and A through Z. By adding in what you have it’s not longer a match as there is nothing called what you’ve added. If you’re doing a word match it wouldn’t look like this anyway it would have a /b and you’d need to add in an or. I’d suggest reading about regex to understand it better.

Comment: Do you have any proper article or some web site to learn regex ?

Comment: Thanks i appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Without using regular expression.

```
long =   """ADDRESS: Some place in the world
    TEL: 555 5555 5555 TYPE: Apartment/High
    Data Accuracy: Very heigh building with plenty of corroborating data"""

indicators = ["ADDRESS", "TEL", "TYPE", "Data Accuracy"]

dict_ = dict()
for indicator in reversed(indicators):
    long, value = long.split(indicator + ":")
    dict_[indicator] = value.strip()

print(dict_)
```

output:

```
{'Data Accuracy': 'Very heigh building with plenty of corroborating data', 'TYPE': 'Apartment/High', 'TEL': '555 5555 5555', 'ADDRESS': 'Some place in the world'}
```

Comment: Thanks thiss is also helpful !!